# 'Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI' using Python Social Auth

Tags: python, django, instagram-api, python-social-auth

I am using [python-social-auth](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/) for authentication with social networks.

I have installed and configured everything. In the last step, I added these two action links:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}">Login with Facebook</a>
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'instagram' %}">Login with Instagram</a>
```

Facebook login is working fine but instagram is giving me the following error:

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}
```

in my settings.py I have these:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_KEY = 'my_key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_SECRET = 'my_secret'
```

and

```
INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8000/shops/edit'
```

the most interesting part is that if I try to do this without [python-social-aut](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/), i.e. using these configurations:

```
INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID = get_env_setting('INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID')
INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET = get_env_setting('INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET')
INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI = get_env_setting('INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI')
```

It is just working fine.

I am thinking it has something to do with that python-social-auth app.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URL for example

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/complete/instagram'
```

and check redirect uri in you instagram client settings.

Comment: I just had to change the redirect uri in my instagram developer account to 'http://localhost:8000/complete/instagram'.